# Microsoft Visual Studio not showing intellisense when typing in app.config for creating ServiceHost

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I am new to WCF( Windows Communication Foundation) services. When I am typing in app.config to do the configurations while creating a host console application, such as defining endpoints, Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 does not show any intelli-sense.

The issue may result in typing wrong tags and the application not to build successfully.

Seems like I have to install something first. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please add your actual code, and not an image of it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the service model XML schema loaded. To load them open your *app.config* file in Visual Studio, an additional menu named *XML* should appear, click it and open *Schemas...*, and check you have all the basic schema loaded.

Additionally, most of the schema files are found in `your VS installation directory\VS version\xml\Schemas\` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, u are right f.nasim.

I think its because I did not load namespace ,System.ServiceModel , in my project.

While implementing the next tutorial, I did not get this issue.